Are Innodb redo logs written atomically?
When flushing dirty pages from buffer pool to disk pages, it uses double write buffering to avoid half written pages. But redo logs do not have such mechanism. So, how does it prevent redo logs from corrupting? Are Innodb redo logs written atomically? If so, how is it implemented? AFAIK, neither O_DIRECT nor writing in sector size guarantees atomicity.

I hope someone comes along with the answer.
